# Can I set a general major.minor.release for a solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, versioning

I know that I can set a major and minor release number for every project in my solution in VS. Can I set a general major.minor number for all my projects in my solution, that all have the same format e.g. 2.3.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I recommend that you have a common file called `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs` that contains the assembly information that applies across your entire solution.** It would probably include the following attributes:

```
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Your Product Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Your Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2010 Your Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("Your Trademark (if applicable)")]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

**Then, each project should have a local file called `AssemblyInfo.cs` that contains the specific information applying only to that project.** This will include the information you might want to supply on a per-assembly basis:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Your Assembly Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Your Assembly Description")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("Assembly Culture (if not neutral)")]

[assembly: ComVisible(true/false)]
[assembly: Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
```

**Finally, follow these steps to share the `GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs` file between multiple projects:**

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, point to "Add", and click "Existing Item."
2. Navigate to your global assembly file and select it.
3. Click the drop-down arrow on the "Add" button, and click "Add As Link" in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You only need to reference (add file as link to your project) in all your projects to a common file e.g. Version.cs which contains the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion common for all your projects.

Yours,
   Alois Kraus

Comment: +1 @user509218 - Also, just in case you arent clear about how to go about doing it check out http://www.tigraine.at/2009/01/22/sharing-a-common-assemblyinfo-between-projects-in-a-solution/

Comment: Do you mean that it's possible to add a reference to a sourcefile? I've always added these kind of files as linked items (Add Existing and then select the "Add as link"-option)

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I do it like the propose of Alois I have an other problem. For every project I need to set the AssemblyProduct Property. If I have one AsssemblyInfo.cs file for all projects, I can just set one AssemblyProduct for all? Is there a possibility to set this property more flexible?

Comment: @user509218: You can be as flexible as you like, including *anything* that can be common for your solution in the global file, and leaving out anything that might need to be specific to individual assemblies. I've had great luck with this approach.